# How to change machine-type of GCP instance group?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to downsize the CPU of all VMs in an instance group. The documentation doesn't specify how to do this.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance

> You can change the machine type of a stopped instance if it is not
>   part of a managed instance group. If you need to change the machine
>   type of instances within a managed instance group, read Updating
>   managed instance groups.

Do I need to create a new instance group template with a smaller machine type, and then run something like this?

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update [INSTANCE_GROUP] \
    --version template=[INSTANCE_TEMPLATE] [--zone [ZONE] | --region [REGION]]
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a new instance template and deploy the new template. You cannot modify an existing instance template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly stated, the command needed to roll out an update to all the instances in a instance group is:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update [INSTANCE_GROUP] \
--version template=[INSTANCE_TEMPLATE] [--zone [ZONE] | --region [REGION]]
```

But first you will need to [create an instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) to pass it to the function above.

The command to do so will look like this:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create example-template-custom \
--machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--image-family debian-9 \
--image-project debian-cloud \
--boot-disk-size 250GB
```

That will create a new instance template from scratch. However, you can also override the settings from an [already existing instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-instance), being able to modify the disk specs. Here you can find a template on how to override an already existing instance template:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create [INSTANCE_TEMPLATE_NAME] \
--source-instance=[SOURCE_INSTANCE] \
--source-instance-zone=[SOURCE_INSTANCE_ZONE] \
[--configure-disk= \
    device-name=[SOURCE_DISK], \
    instantiate-from=[INSTANTIATE_FROM], \
    auto-delete=[AUTO_DELETE]]
```